# Crossed Random Effects in GAM

Tags: mixed-model

I am looking for a function in R which can handle Crossed Random Effects as well as Splines for my Fixed Effects and for the Random Effects. I tried the function gam from mgcv and just specified two different random intercepts. But I am not sure whether the function is really treating my effects as crossed in the background. Does anyone know something more about it or know a more appropriate function in R?